# Interesting issue with my wifi Car project

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

Hello so i build a nodemcu wifi controlled car, everything works fine expect i have one small issue, currently i have 2 9v batterys, one of them is connected to motor controller and other one is connected to nodemcu.. but the nodemcu's 9v battery gets hot in a minute and stops working. What am i doing wrong? + is connected to vcc and - is connected to grnd on nodemcu.

[image]

Comment: Have you measured the current flow from the battery that's getting hot with a multimeter? Have you checked for shorts? Do you need a common ground between the two batteries? Can you upload a complete schematic of your project by using the schematic tool (Ctrl+M)?

Comment: zinc-carbon battery? i did not think that they made those anymore.

Answer (score 2):

> the nodemcu's 9v battery gets hot in a minute and stops working. What am i doing wrong?

You're using a 9V battery.

Those batteries are useless. They have very little capacity, and can provide very little current. The NodeMCU needs a *lot* of current.

Choose a better battery. Maybe a Li-Poly battery would be good (mobile phone batteries are good for this).

Comment: This site suggested 9v batterys http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/powering-the-esp-12e-nodemcu-development-board/

Comment: LG B4 18650 li-ion battery 2600mAh 3.7V, is this okey?

Comment: @SezerYıldız No the site said `This is my least favorite option.` I don't call that a recommendation ;-) For the 18650 you may need a Step-up booster and deep discharge protection if not built in.

Comment: 18650s are good cells. I'm not sure what the LDO dropout on the NodeMCU is off hand, but since a lithium cell is nearer 4.2V when fully charged it should be good for most of its charge range.

Comment: alright, i will open one of my xianomi powerbanks and extract the li ion batterys!

Comment: @SezerYıldız keep the protection circuitry on them intact and connected. That will prevent overdischarge and overcharging; both of which can be dangerous.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Over-discharge of a single cell isn't dangerous. It's not even unrecoverable. What is dangerous is over-discharge of a single cell in a multi-cell (series) pack which causes that cell to reverse charge with the current flowing from the other cells causing copper to pierce the electrolyte layer causing a short internally.

Comment: Why crack out the cells out of a power bank? Just use the 5V / 1A (probably) output of that power bank to power the NodeMCU. That's less work for the LDO / less heat to produce than with the 9V battery, and the USB power bank can output much higher currents.

Comment: Size? Maybe it's a large power bank, but only 1 cell would suffice for the project...

Comment: Yes majenko its a small car, but i have a big powerbank thats why i took out one soon i will post a picture